# mpirun in kubuntu 20.4 stucks

Tags: kubuntu, mpi

I installed kubuntu20.4.1  with openmpi 4.0.3-0 in two different computers. Compiling with mpif90 works, but mpirun stucks with no output in both systems. Even mpirun command without parameters stucks and only twice ctrl-C typing can end the sleeping program.  Is there a possibility to have any method for having messages? Somebody have the same bug?
Thanks